# How to find the derivative of a definite integral where one of the limits is itself an integral

Tags: calculus

Consider

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_3^{\int_ 1 ^x \sin^3t}  \frac{1}{1 + \sin^6t + t^2}dt.$$

I have to find the above derivative as an exercise, I assumed that I’d have to use the Fundamental Theorem, but the result I’m getting seems too complex. Is there any either way to get a simpler and more elegant solution for this?

I tried doing it but ended up with a result that doesn’t seem accurate

$$
 \frac{\sin^3x}{1 + \sin^6{\int_1^x \sin^3t} + (\int_1^x \sin^3tdt)^2}
$$

Comment: You should apply Leibniz integral rule (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Answer (score 0):

Define $$f(y) = \int_3^y  \frac{1}{1 + \sin^6t + t^2}dt $$ and $$ g(x) = \int_1^x \sin^3t \, dt. $$ You want to differentiate $f \circ g$. Using the chain rule, you can see that your result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

if the upper integral was $ \int_1 ^x \sin^3 (t) dt $ (with respect to t) then

let $ g(t) $ be the anti derivative of $ \frac{1}{1 + \sin^6t + t^2}$  and let $f(x) = \int_1 ^x \sin^3 (t) dt $ then

$$\int _3 ^{f(x)}  \frac{1}{1 + \sin^6t + t^2} dt =g(f(x)) -g(3)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(  \int _3 ^{f(x)}  \frac{1}{1 + \sin^6t + t^2} dt\right) = 
 g'(f(x)) f'(x) = \frac{\sin^3 (t) }{1 + \sin^6(\int_1 ^x \sin^3 (t)dt ) + (\int_1 ^x \sin^3 (t)  dt )^2}$$

as @ayan pointed in the comments $\int_1^x \sin^3(t)dt =\frac{1}{3}(\cos^3(x) - \cos(x) -\cos^3(1) + \cos(1)) $ but I so the formula would be
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(  \int _3 ^{f(x)}  \frac{1}{1 + \sin^6t + t^2} dt\right)  = \frac{\sin^3 (t) }{1 + \sin^6(\frac{1}{3}(\cos^3(x) - \cos(x) -\cos^3(1) + \cos(1)) ) + (\frac{1}{3}(\cos^3(x) - \cos(x) -\cos^3(1) + \cos(1))  )^2}$$

Comment: @ayan I know that but it would be very ugly formula If I wrote that

Comment: just added it in for reference sake :) (hope you dont mind)